# Say $A\subseteq\mathbb{R},f:A\to\mathbb{R},$ and $c\in A$ is not a cluster point. Why is $f$ continuous at $c$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Say $A\subseteq\mathbb{R},f:A\to\mathbb{R},$ and $c\in A$ is not a cluster point. I'm wondering, intuitively, why is $f$ continuous at $c$? We can easily prove this technically. Since $c$ is not a cluster point of $A$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\{x:0<|x-c|<\delta\}\bigcap A=\emptyset.$  Suppose $\epsilon>0.$ If $|x-c|<\delta$ and $x\in A,$ then $x=c,$ and we have $|f(x)-f(c)|=|f(c)-f(c)|=0<\epsilon.$ So $f$ is continuous at $c$. I understand the proof, it would just help to understand this on more of an intuitive level rather than a technical level. I remember learning in calculus that a continuous function is the type of function where you don’t need to pick up your pencil when you draw it, but clearly continuity is more than that. Can anyone shed light on the intuitive aspect of this? Thank you!

Comment: The essence of continuity is that you can control the closeness of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ by controlling the closeness of $x$ and $y$. In your scenario, on a small enough scale, there are no points close to $c$ other than $c$ itself. So continuity is almost vacuously present.

Comment: The intuition from calculus applies only when the domain is an interval. This result is probing the exact opposite direction—namely when the domain has isolated points.

Comment: Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions to contain important information. The body of your question should be self-contained. If I was reading your question using the MSE Android app, I wouldn't be able to read the formulas in the title, so the question wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you, I did not know that was a problem on Androids (I'm an iPhone user myself). I just adjusted the question.

Comment: The intuition about not having to lift the pencil while drawing the graph doesn't work very well if the domain of definition of the function is not an interval.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question to incorporate the information from the title. There are other good reasons for making the body of your questions self-contained, not least that people often just don't read the title once they've opened up the question.